# Verifying a solution to a given differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hi fellow mathematicians,

I am a physics major trying to bulk up on my ODE before I take it in the Fall, as I have a pretty hard professor. I worked up to this problem and have no idea how the book comes up with their solution.

## 22

$$\frac{{dy}}{{dx}} = 1 - 2xy
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaWaaSaaaeaaca
% WGKbGaamyEaaqaaiaadsgacaWG4baaaiabg2da9iaaigdacqGHsisl
% caaIYaGaamiEaiaadMhaaaa!3F35!
$$ where $$y = ({e^{ - {x^2}}})\int\limits_0^x {{e^{{t^2}}}dt + c_1{e^{ - {x^2}}}} 
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaamyEaiabg2
% da9iaacIcacaWGLbWaaWbaaSqabeaacqGHsislcaWG4bWaaWbaaWqa
% beaacaaIYaaaaaaakiaacMcadaWdXbqaaiaadwgadaahaaWcbeqaai
% aadshadaahaaadbeqaaiaaikdaaaaaaOGaamizaiaadshacqGHRaWk
% caWGJbadcaaIXaGccaWGLbWaaWbaaSqabeaacqGHsislcaWG4bWaaW
% baaWqabeaacaaIYaaaaaaaaSqaaiaaicdaaeaacaWG4baaniabgUIi
% Ydaaaa!4CD1!
$$

I began trying to simplify y by integrating over

$$\int\limits_0^x {{e^{{t^2}}}dt} 
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbiqaaWGbdaWdXb
% qaaiaadwgadaahaaWcbeqaaiaadshadaahaaadbeqaaiaaikdaaaaa
% aOGaamizaiaadshaaSqaaiaaicdaaeaacaWG4baaniabgUIiYdaaaa!3F0E!
$$

and multiplying by  $$({e^{ - {x^2}}})
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaaiikaiaadw
% gadaahaaWcbeqaaiabgkHiTiaadIhadaahaaadbeqaaiaaikdaaaaa
% aOGaaiykaaaa!3B41!
$$

and splitting up the integral I was able to come up with an answer of

$$({e^{ - {x^2}}})({e^{2x}} - 1)
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaaiikaiaadw
% gadaahaaWcbeqaaiabgkHiTiaadIhadaahaaadbeqaaiaaikdaaaaa
% aOGaaiykaiaacIcacaWGLbWaaWbaaSqabeaacaaIYaGaamiEaaaaki
% abgkHiTiaaigdacaGGPaaaaa!411C!
$$ but when integrating over $$c1\int\limits_0^x {{e^{ - {x^2}}}} 
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbiqaaWGbcaWGJb
% adcaaIXaGcdaWdXbqaaiaadwgadaahaaWcbeqaaiabgkHiTiaadIha
% daahaaadbeqaaiaaikdaaaaaaaWcbaGaaGimaaqaaiaadIhaa0Gaey
% 4kIipaaaa!3FCC!
$$

would you utilize the constant outside the integrand and u substitute $$({e^{ - {x^2}}})c_1\int\limits_0^x {{e^{ - {x^2}}}} 
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbiqaaWGbcaGGOa
% GaamyzamaaCaaaleqabaGaeyOeI0IaamiEamaaCaaameqabaGaaGOm
% aaaaaaGccaGGPaGaam4yaWGaaGymaOWaa8qCaeaacaWGLbWaaWbaaS
% qabeaacqGHsislcaWG4bWaaWbaaWqabeaacaaIYaaaaaaaaSqaaiaa
% icdaaeaacaWG4baaniabgUIiYdaaaa!451A!
$$
[Problem 22 solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPcLl.jpg)

after trying to compute and verify myself, I finally looked up the solution and am I correct in assuming they took the derivative over the integrand and did a product rule? Can someone explain how they were able to get that solution for y prime and ultimately how one would plug y and y prime back into $$\frac{{dy}}{{dx}} = 1 - 2xy
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaWaaSaaaeaaca
% WGKbGaamyEaaqaaiaadsgacaWG4baaaiabg2da9iaaigdacqGHsisl
% caaIYaGaamiEaiaadMhaaaa!3F35!
$$
to verify the solution??

Comment: The solution is given by $$y(x)=c_1 e^{-x^2}+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } e^{-x^2}
   \text{erfi}(x)$$

Comment: They are using $\left(\int_0^x e^{-t^2}\mathop{dt}\right)'=e^{-x^2}$. The rest is just usage of product rule derivation. In the end they make the integral cancel by adding $y'$ and $2xy$.

Comment: Ohhh ok. I thought it was something like that! You rock! thankyou

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic example of a linear ODE. You should read on it to get how to solve this ODE.

Also, to  verify the solution, the first step is to compute $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

We have - 
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{ - x^2}\int\limits_0^x {e^{t^2}}dt\right) + c_1\frac{d(e^{-x^2})}{dx} \\\
&=\frac{d(e^{-x^2})}{dx}\int\limits_0^x {e^{t^2}}dt + e^{ - x^2}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int\limits_0^x {e^{t^2}}dt\right) + c_1\frac{d(e^{-x^2})}{dx}\\
&=(-2x)e^{-x^2}\int\limits_0^x {e^{t^2}}dt + e^{-x^2}e^{x^2} + c_1(-2x)e^{-x^2}\\
&=1 + (-2x)e^{-x^2}\int\limits_0^x {e^{t^2}}dt + c_1(-2x)e^{-x^2}
\end{align}
(as by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^x f(t)dt = f(x)$)

Through this, we can compute $y'+2xy$ and get the answer as $1$, thus verifying the solution.

Comment: Thankyou, that was a very helpful step by step solution

Comment: did the plus one outside of the integrand come from $$({e^{ - {x^2}}})({e^{{x^2}}})
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaaiikaiaadw
% gadaahaaWcbeqaaiabgkHiTiaadIhadaahaaadbeqaaiaaikdaaaaa
% aOGaaiykaiaacIcacaWGLbWaaWbaaSqabeaacaWG4bWaaWbaaWqabe
% aacaaIYaaaaaaakiaacMcaaaa!3FA2!
$$

Comment: Yup. That it did.

Comment: Thanks again! :-D